# Problem REACT img dont work in json folder

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use several images located in a file, my JSON file contains the url of this file and its image, so I use a map to display all the data in the JSON, all works except the img which is are not loaded so I tried to use a remote url and it works here is the code.

Here is the code I'm working with :

[image]

The JSON file looks like the following :

[image]

Comment: [Please don't upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

In your json file import the images and then use the import variables on the items.
Example

```js
import cat from '../../img/cat.jpg';

export default [{
  imageSource: cat
}];
```

That way webpack can pickup these images and include them in the bundle